# Codeigniter - multiple input with loop

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, foreach, multiple-insert

I wanted to make the multiple inputs form with loop and the different value for each data I fill, it seems this code is working but it was only getting 1 data to 3 times with the same value.

what I need is that I can make different value for each data in the form.

Or maybe do I need a model for this one or something? been struggle for few days here please help.

this is what i expect for the result in the form loop

[image]

but I want to get this Output:-
[image]

**controller.php**

```
public function aksi_soal3(){
        $ps5 = $this->input->post('soal');
        $ps6 = $this->input->post('opsi_a');
        $ps7 = $this->input->post('opsi_b');
        $ps11 = $this->input->post('kunci_jawaban');

        $data = array(
            array(
                'soal' => $ps5,
                'opsi_a' => $ps6,
                'opsi_b' => $ps7,
                'kunci_jawaban' => $ps11
            ),
            array(
                'soal' => $ps5,
                'opsi_a' => $ps6,
                'opsi_b' => $ps7,
                'kunci_jawaban' => $ps11
            ),
            array(
                'soal' => $ps5,
                'opsi_a' => $ps6,
                'opsi_b' => $ps7,
                'kunci_jawaban' => $ps11
            )
        );

        $this->db->insert_batch('soal',$data);
        redirect('guru/index');
    }
```

**view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<=3){
foreach($tampilan as $soal){
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>guru/aksi_soal3" method="post">
    
        <?php
    echo "  
            <input type='hidden' name='kode_soal' value='$soal->kode_soal''>
            <textarea placeholder='soal' name='soal'></textarea>

            <input type='text' name='opsi_a' placeholder='jawaban a'>
            <input type='text' name='opsi_b' placeholder='jawaban b'>
            <input type='text' name='kunci_jawaban' placeholder='Kunci jawaban' >
            </div>
            </div>
     ";
    ?>

        <?php
    $i=$i+1;
}}
?>   

<button type="submit" class="btn">Selesai</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand bro,u want to get an array in the controller? could u explain more what u expect to see?

Comment: You have used the same name in the input it will overwrite your previous value, you need to add the name as an array like name='kode_soal[]'

Comment: i wanted to make multiple input with different value for example 
data 1:
soal:tes1
opsi_a:tes1
opsi_b:tes1
kunci_jawaban:tes1
data 2:
soal:tes2
opsi_a:tes2
opsi_b:tes2
kunci_jawaban:tes2
data 3:
soal:tes3
opsi_a:tes3
opsi_b:tes3
kunci_jawaban:tes3

Comment: the problem right now is just only taking data 3 only and make it become three row with only tes3 but not involved data 1 and data 2 in the database so all the data row is tes3

Comment: You're actually creating multiple forms. Is that intentional?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes that is so that i can make different value for that

Comment: But when you post a form, only that data will be sent so your controller will only get 5 values. Then the array you're creating in the controller doesn't make sense. Can you please update your question with a proper explanation of what you're trying to do and what the expected result is? It's very unclear.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so you mean  i need to make different form? for each different value that i want to get and is like i need 5 form for 5 different value? is that what you mean?

Comment: No, that's what you're currently creating. If you want to post all data at the same time, you need to create your loop _inside_ the form tags instead of having the form tags inside the loop. You should only have _one_ form. You also need to add `[]` after you names (as others have suggested) to get the input values as arrays in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like below,

**Controller Part :-**

```php
    public function aksi_soal3(){
            $ps5 = $this->input->post('soal');
            $ps6 = $this->input->post('opsi_a');
            $ps7 = $this->input->post('opsi_b');
            $ps11 = $this->input->post('kunci_jawaban');
         $data = array();
        foreach($ps5 as $key=>$value) {
            $data[]  = array(
                    'soal' => $value,
                    'opsi_a' => $ps6[$key],
                    'opsi_b' => $ps7[$key],
                    'kunci_jawaban' => $ps11[$key]
                );
        }
            $this->db->insert_batch('soal',$data);
            redirect('guru/index');
        }
```

**View Part :-**

```html
    <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>guru/aksi_soal3" method="post">
    
    <input type='hidden' name='kode_soal[]' value='$soal->kode_soal''>
    <textarea placeholder='soal' name='soal[]'></textarea>
    <input type='text' name='opsi_a[]' placeholder='jawaban a'>
    <input type='text' name='opsi_b[]' placeholder='jawaban b'>
    <input type='text' name='kunci_jawaban[]' placeholder='Kunci jawaban' >
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Selesai</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This won't work since the OP is creating multiple forms as well.

Comment: you need to put a form outside of a loop.

Comment: okay it works now i can make different value with this, thanks a lot. I've been trying to crack this out for few days XD and also i have put the form outside of the loop

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="after-add-more">
<input type="text"name="StudentID[]" value="">
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="form-group remove">
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-fill add-more">Add More</button>
</div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("body").on("click",".add-more",function(){
    var html = $(".after-add-more:first").clone();
    $(html).find(".remove").html("<br><a class='btn btn-danger btn-fill remove'>Remove</a>");
  $(".after-add-more").last().after(html);
});
$("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
    $(this).parents(".after-add-more").remove();
});
});
```

you need something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/cudkfraj/

when you click on add more button, the text field populate as many as you click, then you can change the name attribute of your form field to be like that code, with bracket[] so you can save your value as an array